# Extended formatting of expressions within a query

Tags: ms-access

I'm writing a query to output to a report which will be printed and used as an internal business form.  I'm having issues trying to get the date placeholders to output for records where these values are null.  It's probably just easier to show the code:

```
IStatement: "For a period from " & Nz(FormatDateTime([DateFrom],2),"________") & " to " & Nz(FormatDateTime([DateTo],2),"________") & "inclusive at the rate of " & Nz(FormatCurrency([InclusiveRate]),"$______") & " per " & [InclusiveTimeFrame]
```

I'm trying to get a blank line eight spaces wide to display in the query when there is not date in the record.  What the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormatDateTime`
will return string and never null hence your `Nz` isn't working. However, you could try `iif(not isnull([DateFrom]), FormatDateTime([DateFrom],2),"________")`

or write your custom function for validating the date field.